# Import another Texture at runtime (three.js with .glb Format)

Tags: 3d, three.js, blender, gltf

I am trying to change a texture of an .glb object at runtime. I am using three.js and it will not work.

As in this example it has to work... http://necromanthus.com/Test/html5/sims_room.html

So, I have this object:
(glb export with embedded image)
[Shoe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FYr4.png)

Now I change the texture and something wild like this happens:
[Shoe after change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZFq1.png)

I have no Idea what I can do.

Here is the code of loading the .glb object:

```
var shoeFile = 'shoe.glb';
glbLoader.load('3d_models/' + shoeFile, function(geometry) {
  shoeObject = geometry.scene.children[0];
  scene.add(shoeObject);
}, onLoadProgress);
```

Here is the code for changing the texture:

```
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var remap = textureLoader.load( "3d_models/shoe.png" );

function setAnotherTexture( texture ) {
   scene.children[5].material.map = eval( texture );
}
```

Is my code wrong or is there a trick to export another texture in blender?

Hope someone can help me with it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what `eval( texture )` is doing, but whatever texture you assign to `material.map`, make sure you've set `texture.flipY = false` on it.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy fantastic, it is working. Thank you soooo much.

Comment: Great to hear! Added an answer describing this in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glTF format uses a different texture convention than three.js, and `texture.flipY` must be set to `false` (its default is `true`). For textures included in a model, GLTFLoader does this automatically. When changing out the texture or adding a new texture at runtime, this must be done in your JS code:

```
texture.flipY = false;
mesh.material.map = texture;
```